# What are the POSIX like functions in MSVC's C runtime?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

Today I stumbled to MSDN's documents about Visual C++'s C runtime (example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8syseb29.aspx) and find to my surprise a lot of functions that look just like POSIX syscalls: `dup2`, `fdopen`, `stat`, `execlp`, ..., except being prefixed with `_` or `_w`. Are these functions just wrappers to Windows API? Are they only usable with the POSIX subsystem? Are they deprecated/going to be deprecated?

Comment: Windows once supported 3 api layers.  Win32, OS/2 and Posix.  Win32 won by a landslide.  The posix functions are still supported but got the leading underscore since they are not otherwise OS or standard C functions.  You can use them in a win32 program, it will try its best to make it functional.  Don't expect miracles, a function like _stat() isn't going to tell you anything about an inode of course.  And no _fork(), that's too alien.

Comment: There's a list of "deprecated" POSIX functions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235384.aspx (Deprecated in the sense that they will cause deprecation warnings as non-standard CRT/C++ Standard Library functions, not in the sense that they are likely to go away anytime soon.) A few of the POSIX functions made it into the C99 or ISO C++ standard, and aren't deprecated.

Comment: @ColinRobertson: But `_stat` is not (or is it?) deprecated, and its syntax is the same as `stat`. I do not care about POSIX conformance, I just find the POSIX-like api easier to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions are wrappers around Win32 APIs. You don't need to have the POSIX subsystem to use them. They are not likely to disappear - Microsoft takes backwards compatibility very seriously.

You can find the source code of the MS CRT in "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio X.0\VC\crt\src". E.g. you can see that `_dup2` is calling `DuplicateHandle` and `_stat` is using `FindFirstFileEx`.

As for why they got the underscores, I could not find an official reason, but I suspect it's probably because these functions don't provide full POSIX compliance.

Comment: [§17.6.4.3.2b](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf)  "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.". That's the rationale behind it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know that *some* of the non-underscored functions are part of the C standard (e.g, `fwrite` is specified in C11, §7.21.8.2), while others are specified in the POSIX standard, and are *not* part of the C standard (e.g. `strdup`).

Now Windows is not 100% POSIX-compliant, so these *POSIX-like* functions may or may not behave according to the POSIX specification. It is quite possible that some C application that relies on POSIX behavior of these functions may compile but not run on Windows or run but work incorrectly.

To try to prevent this, MSVC greets you with a warning every time you try to use them:

> warning C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated.
>   Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for
>   details.

Now, although this *sounds* like `_strdup` is standardized by ISO, it is *not*; it's just weaselease for "*Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation*", [[lib.global.names]/2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/lib-intro.html#lib.global.names).

Microsoft is basically offering you *another name*, `_strdup`, which does not come with the POSIX baggage attached to it. You probably won't find it on any other platform, though.

In the end, there is only one implementation, `_strdup`, the linker simply maps `strdup` to `_strdup` (see [oldnames.lib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zebz5fw.aspx)).